# Fast approximate mapping of string or number(gene) to string or number(gene template)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

I'm writing a genetic algorithm and wanted to spice it up a little.

I have 500 template genes - randomly generated list of numbers/strings, what you think is better to compute similarity. And I have a DNA of size 300-800 genes - some numbers/strings as well.

What I want is to iterate over DNA and map each gene from it to one(**or many**) of the template genes and add up its influence.

Here is my take on it(genes - DNA):

```
n = 500
step = 2**32/(n + 1)
random.seed(10)
template_genes = sorted(np.random.random_integers(0, 2**32, n))
n_g = n
genes = np.random.random_integers(0, 2**32, n_g)
d = {i:0 for i in range(n)}
import time

buckets = [[] for i in range(n+1)]
a = time.clock()
for i in range(n_g):
    buckets[int(genes[i]//step)].append(genes[i])

for i in range(n):
    w = int(template_genes[i]//step)
    for g in buckets[w]:
        d[i] += max(0, 1 - abs(template_genes[i] - g)/step)*0.5
    #if w - 1 > 0:
    #    for g in buckets[w-1]:
    #        d[i] += max(0, 1 - abs(template_genes[i] - g)/step)*0.5
    #if w + 1 < n+1:
    #    for g in buckets[w+1]:
    #        d[i] += max(0, 1 - abs(template_genes[i] - g)/step)*0.5
    # lines above are commented because it was too slow.
print(time.clock() - a)
```

What it does:

Divides 2**32 by number of template genes into buckets, iterates over genes(DNA) and places them into buckets, then iterates over template_genes and sums up influence of genes based on their distance from template_gene.

It's a very sloppy gathering of gene influence. Initially I had a nested loop inside template_genes iteration that was iterating over all DNA genes and summing influence inside -+step. But it was working very slow for a 1000/1000 genes. This one works faster, but still too slow for my purposes.
The code above takes 14ms and if I uncomment those additional iterations - 3 times as much.

Any ideas how to make it work faster or some totally different approach?

Comment: Each loop will increase execution complexity to O(n). If you have double nested loop , it will increase to O(n^2). Perhaps you can look at other algorithms such as "Binary search" for which complexity is O(logn). Even if you sort the list for first time, the complexity will still be O(nlogn) which will still be less than O(n^2) you are experiencing for two loops.